# Homepage - Products block wider than screen in mobile- How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On the homepage, Block product is wider than my screen in mobile, no idea how to resolve.

[www.pantonedinhtran.com](http://www.pantonedinhtran.com) is my webpage, but only mobile affected.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP3Tn.jpg)

Any CSS code of function to solve this?? Thanks.

Comment: you can use flex and please add your code as a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add display block to the main div, 
if you use the following code, your issue will be gone

```
.porto-products.show-category {
 display: block;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: Hi, can this code apply for only mobile devices? Cause my web has an issue on the desktop when using it. https://i.imgur.com/XWTcBsy.png

Comment: you can apply this to the small screens only by using media queries, you will need to warp this code above inside one, please check this page.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Perfect bro! I studied finance and I'm so amateur at coding. Thank you lots.

Comment: we are all learners :), even after 5 years of working every day as a programmer you will still need to ask questions and find answers ;)